# Prevent to close browser after @After

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to prevent browser to close after my test scenario, I have tried several things found from online resources but nothing worked so far.

The goal is to prevent the browser to get closed and keep manually from a certain point, like a 'checkpoint', is there any way to do this?

I have tried :

```
@After("@leave_window_open")
```

but seems it is working only if the Scenario is failing.

is there any simple way to block this behavior, and avoiding debugging?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep the browser open after test execution when using selenium web driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247536/how-to-keep-the-browser-open-after-test-execution-when-using-selenium-web-driver)

Comment: sorry it is not useful, my goal is to keep it open and continue manually

Comment: @OEH What is "@leave_window_open"? What happens if u do not call quit or close on the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser won't close unless you call `.close()` or `.quit()`. You must have those calls somewhere... just remove them. If you are looking for a intermittent fix, just add a breakpoint where you want the script to stop. Once the run breaks, stop the execution and continue manually. I do this all the time for debugging purposes.

Comment: I thought about this... could not find any reference to those two functions, thank I thought it is an out of the box behaviour